# iPhone app code-signing error - "...the signature was invalid..."

Tags: iphone, xcode, codesign

I am trying to upload my first iOS app to iTunes Connect, but I am unable to do this because every time I try to upload it, I receive the following error from Application Loader:

> The binary you uploaded was invalid.
>   The signature was invalid, or it was
>   not signed with an Apple submission
>   certificate

I have followed the instructions on the Apple website to the best of my ability. **I have noticed that the .mobileprovision file that should be in my built .app file is missing** - does anyone know what would cause this particular part of the problem to happen? I suspect it could be the root cause.

Moreover, does anyone have any other suggestions as to how I might correct this issue?

Comment: Are u create distribution file with admin id and password.

Answer (score 0):

on the agent account in developer.apple.com

You must create a distribution certificate

You must also create a Distribution Provisioning Profile.

Download both of these and drag them onto xcode.

In the target info for your project you need to go to the code signing section and make sure you have selected your distribution profile.

Another thing you may need to do is create an entitlements file, declare this under 'code signing entitlements' as described on the apple page here

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/index.action